# docx4j ObjectFactory set font style to title

Tags: java, docx4j, objectfactory

I'm creating a word document using docx4j and I need to style the 'Title', however, I cannot find the right function to do this.

```
private static P createIt() {

    org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory wmlObjectFactory = new org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory();

    P p = wmlObjectFactory.createP();
    // Create object for pPr
    PPr ppr = wmlObjectFactory.createPPr();

    p.setPPr(ppr);
    // Create object for pStyle
    PPrBase.PStyle pprbasepstyle = wmlObjectFactory.createPPrBasePStyle(); 
    ppr.setPStyle(pprbasepstyle); 
    pprbasepstyle.setVal( "Title");
    // Create object for r
    R r = wmlObjectFactory.createR(); 
    p.getContent().add(r); 
    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped); 
    text.setValue( "\u041E\u041E\u041E \u00AB\u0418\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u041F\u043E\u043B\u00BB"); 

    // Create object for br
    Br br = wmlObjectFactory.createBr(); 
    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text2 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped2 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text2); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped2); 
    text2.setValue( "630001, \u041D\u043E\u0432\u043E\u0441\u0438\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043A\u0430\u044F \u043E\u0431\u043B\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044C, \u0433. \u041D\u043E\u0432\u043E\u0441\u0438\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043A, \u0443\u043B. \u0421\u0443\u0445\u0430\u0440\u043D\u0430\u044F, \u0434.35, \u043A\u043E\u0440\u043F.4, \u043E\u0444\u0438\u0441 406"); 

    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text3 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped3 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text3); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped3); 
    text3.setValue( "\u0422\u0435\u043B. (383) 375-70-35, 8-909-529-57-57"); 

    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text4 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped4 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text4); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped4); 
    text4.setValue( "e-mail: info@interpol-nsk.ru, \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442: www.interpol-nsk.ru"); 

    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text5 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped5 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text5); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped5); 
    text5.setValue( "\u0418\u041D\u041D 5402549079 \u041A\u041F\u041F 540201001, \u041E\u0413\u0420\u041D 1125476048983"); 

    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text6 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped6 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text6); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped6); 
    text6.setValue( "\u0440/\u0441 40702810401300023124 \u0432 \u00AB\u0411\u0430\u043D\u043A24.\u0440\u0443\u00BB (\u041E\u0410\u041E) \u0433.\u0415\u043A\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u043D\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433"); 

    r.getContent().add(br); 

    // Create object for t (wrapped in JAXBElement) 
    Text text7 = wmlObjectFactory.createText(); 
    JAXBElement<org.docx4j.wml.Text> textWrapped7 = wmlObjectFactory.createRT(text7); 
    r.getContent().add(textWrapped7); 
    text7.setValue( "\u0411\u0418\u041A 046577859, \u043A/\u0441 30101810600000000859 \u0432 \u0413\u0420\u041A\u0426 \u0413\u0423 \u0411\u0430\u043D\u043A\u0430 \u0420\u043E\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0438 \u043F\u043E \u0421\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0434\u043B\u043E\u0432\u0441\u043A\u043E\u0439 \u043E\u0431\u043B\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\r\u041E\u041E\u041E \u00AB\u0418\u043D\u0442\u0435\u0440\u041F\u043E\u043B\u00BB\r630001, \u041D\u043E\u0432\u043E\u0441\u0438\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043A\u0430\u044F \u043E\u0431\u043B\u0430\u0441\u0442\u044C, \u0433. \u041D\u043E\u0432\u043E\u0441\u0438\u0431\u0438\u0440\u0441\u043A, \u0443\u043B. \u0421\u0443\u0445\u0430\u0440\u043D\u0430\u044F, \u0434.35, \u043A\u043E\u0440\u043F.4, \u043E\u0444\u0438\u0441 406\r\u0422\u0435\u043B. (383) 375-70-35, 8-909-529-57-57\re-mail: info@interpol-nsk.ru, \u0441\u0430\u0439\u0442: www.interpol-nsk.ru\r\u0418\u041D\u041D 5402549079 \u041A\u041F\u041F 540201001, \u041E\u0413\u0420\u041D 1125476048983\r\u0440/\u0441 40702810401300023124 \u0432 \u00AB\u0411\u0430\u043D\u043A24.\u0440\u0443\u00BB (\u041E\u0410\u041E) \u0433.\u0415\u043A\u0430\u0442\u0435\u0440\u0438\u043D\u0431\u0443\u0440\u0433\r\u0411\u0418\u041A 046577859, \u043A/\u0441 30101810600000000859 \u0432 \u0413\u0420\u041A\u0426 \u0413\u0423 \u0411\u0430\u043D\u043A\u0430 \u0420\u043E\u0441\u0441\u0438\u0438 \u043F\u043E \u0421\u0432\u0435\u0440\u0434\u043B\u043E\u0432\u0441\u043A\u043E\u0439 \u043E\u0431\u043B\u0430\u0441\u0442\u0438\r");

    return p;
}
```

I need to change the font to times new roman and size 10.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are setting the style to "Title".  Whether that's defined in the document's styles part is another question.

When you say "change the font to times new roman and size 10", do you mean change the Title style definition?  Because if you just mean the run, you can use the docx4j webapp to generate that code.

Comment: I've changed my tactic and edited the template with docx4j. Much easier.

Answer (score 2):

This may helpful for setting the hard code text in word document..

wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Title","This title is now in Arial");
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Subtitle","Arial");
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Heading1","As is Heading1");
wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addStyledParagraphOfText("Heading2","Heading2 is now Arialand fontsize 12");

This may helpful for setting the hard code text in word document..

but i need to set the font size and family whole document Is there any way?

Comment: You should ask this in a new question.  But briefly, you do that in your styles part, in docDefaults/rPrDefaults.